# Is there link between the number of possible binary trees as a function of the tree's height?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, catalan

Dealing with balanced and unbalanced binary trees.

```
height = 0, possible trees = 1 (nothing)
height = 1, possible trees = 1 (leaf)
height = 2, possible trees = 3
```

I'm looking at the Catalan function but it has not lead me anywhere beneficial, mostly because I think it might be counting trees less than height h. For example, if height it 2, it will count height 1 too (and maybe height 0) I believe.

Comment: Related: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14043/number-of-binary-trees-with-given-height. They are able to pinpoint the growth order of the function (`a^(2^h)` for some `a>1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be looking for integer sequence [A001699](https://oeis.org/A001699), "Number of binary trees of height n". One possible algorithm to generate them being:

> a(n+1) = 2*a(n)*(a(0)+...+a(n-1))+a(n)^2

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a closed-form version. Each formula is itself recursive, or uses A003095, which is also recursive.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is relatively easy to evaluate using dynamic programming.